# issue with using double grave accent (backtick) in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to figure out which files I need to modify; so by that, I use sequences of grep commands. I want to find out which files contain both foo and bar. Therefore, my command is:
`` grep foo `grep bar * -l` | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq `` 
This command gets me a big list that looks like this:
pageABC.txt 
pageBCD.txt 
pageDEF.txt

I want this output to be opened in emacs. So what I'd normally do is:
 `` emacs ` whatever_was_in_my_output ` `` 
This command normally opens all the files.
If I try 
`` emacs `grep foo `grep bar * -l` | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq ` `` 
Emacs won't even start. Maybe it's because of the double grave accents used.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Many Thanks,

D

Comment: Rather than piping through `awk`, you could also pass `-l` to the outer `grep`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to escape the inner command substitution:

```
emacs `grep foo \`grep bar * -l\` | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq`
```

In cases like this, I usually prefer the alternative command substition syntax, since it nests  more easily:

```
emacs $(grep foo $(grep bar * -l) | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq)
```

Comment: Also note the traditional `ARG_MAX` warning http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#arg-max.  A more robust, scalable solution would be `grep -l bar * | xargs grep -l foo | sort -u | xargs emacs` ... with the possible comment that `xargs emacs` is overkill (you hardly want to open more than Emacs instance, even if you don't want to hit "bash: Argument list too long" errors; but then you have `emacsclient` for those kinds of situations).

Answer (score 3):

Avoid backticks in bash, and use `$(command)` to run sub-commands.  They nest properly, unlike backticks.